# Flutter - "Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI" on http.post() with localhost API

Tags: flutter, rest, dart

When I make a post request with Postman everything works as expected:

[image]

but the same request using flutter fails with error **Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI**

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

// *****

Future<String> authenticate({
   @required String username,
   @required String password,
}) async {

final response = await http.post(
  'http://localhost:8080/auth',
  body: {
    'username': username,
    'password': password,
  }
);

  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  return responseJson["token"];
}
```

can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: Try adding the headers  `Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
       'Content-type': 'application/json',
       'Accept': 'application/json'
     };`

Comment: @TinusJackson adding recommended code causes - error: Bad state: Cannot set the body fields of a Request with content-type "application/json". }

Comment: Like this? ```Future<String> authenticate({
  @required String username,
  @required String password,
}) async {
  Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'Accept': 'application/json'
  };

  final response = await http.post(
    'http://localhost:8080/auth',
    body: {
      'username': username,
      'password': password,
    },
    headers: requestHeaders,
  );

  final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
  return responseJson["token"];
}```

Comment: @TinusJackson yes

Comment: you are using localhost which is wrong because it tries to call on himself. Use your local pc address instead.

Comment: Did you solve it? All other urls are working except one only

Comment: use your ip address to call API

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the IP address of the localhost machine instead of 'localhost'. Then make sure that internet permission is added on the Android manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`